# how to handle a socket exception

Tags: c#, sockets, xamarin, exception, system

I tried to check if my error message will appear if I'm not connected to the server, but it crushes and it doesn't execute the catch instruction. (No issues when I'm connected to the server)

Here is part of my code:

```
int attempts = 0;
while (!clientSocket.Connected)
{
    try
    {
        attempts++;
        gettext.Text = "Connection attempts:" + attempts.ToString();
        await clientSocket.ConnectAsync("172.20.10.4", 100);
    }
    catch (SocketException)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", "Couldn't connect", "OK");
    }
}

gettext.Text = "Connected";
```

Comment: Try a dummy url for testing, and is DisplayAlert async method ? Why would you wait for it ?

Comment: 'but it crushes' because of an unhandled exeption? Try adding a `catch (Exception ex)` block above your `catch (SocketException)` block and see what type of exception is thrown.

Comment: @AliBenZarrouk my method is Async'd

Comment: If the await method is cancelled, you won't get a SocketException, but an OperationCanceledException. Check out the answer from nilsK

Comment: @DagBaardsen I tried it :/

Comment: And if you add a finally-block and add some dummy code to it?

Comment: @DagBaardsen the error apparently is coming from the "await clientSocket.ConnectAsync("172.20.10.4", 100);" line  . I know I'm not connected to the server , that's the main goal , to display an alert message that im not connected , but instead it crushes